# Populate column from other column for each row in a group

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm in a data migration exercise and have a s/sheet of over 100K rows and so I need a solution beyond a manual update.

For the sake of this post I'll simplify the problem: I have a s/sheet with three columns (A, B & C) with headings [data type] as follows: Name [text], ID [number], CreateDate [date]. The data has been sorted on Col A to deliberately bring the duplicate values in that column into focus. The IDs are unique; the dates are **not** unique.

In the example there are nine rows which can be 'grouped' into three groups by virtue of duplicated values in column A. So for rows 2 and 3 the value in Col A is `abc`, for rows 4, 5 & 6 the value in Col A is `def`,
and for rows 7-10 it is `ghi`.

The first task is to determine the latest CreateDate in each of the 'row-groups'. So in this example that would be 5/11/1999 for rows 2 and 3, 3/12/2001 for rows 4 to 6, and 5/11/1999 for rows 7-10. 
I do this by using the array formula `{=MAX(IF(A2=$A:$A,$C:$C))}`
in column D.

The next task is proving difficult. Now that I have determined the latest date for each row-group, I want to put the ID that corresponds to that LatestDate in column E (on each row of the row-group), so that the result would look like Column E in the below example. But I need to do it with a formula/function, not manually. This is for a migration project so it doesn't have to be pretty.

Putting the matching ID in column E in the same row is easy (an IF statement) – see rows 3, 6 and 9 – but I'm not pretending that's the solution. But I can't work out how to populate the other rows in each group with that same ID – in my attached example that would be rows 2, 4 & 5, 7 & 8, and 10. 
I can't just do a lookup in Column C because those values are not unique. 
After futile attempts with various formulae I am at a loss. My guess is that it needs to rely on column C (the matching values), and functions such as `INDEX` and `MATCH` ... or maybe VBA.

```
     +------+------+------------+------------+-----------------+
     |  A   |   B  |     C      |     D      |        E        |
+----+------+------+------------+------------+-----------------+
|  1 | Name |  ID  | CreateDate | LatestDate | CorrespondingID |
|  2 | abc  |   1  | 4/12/1998  | 5/11/1999  |         2       |
|  3 | abc  |   2  | 5/11/1999  | 5/11/1999  |         2       |
|  4 | def  |   3  | 1/12/1999  | 3/12/2001  |         5       |
|  5 | def  |   4  | 5/11/1999  | 3/12/2001  |         5       |
|  6 | def  |   5  | 3/12/2001  | 3/12/2001  |         5       |
|  7 | ghi  |  17  | 1/17/1999  | 5/11/1999  |        55       |
|  8 | ghi  |  42  | 2/4/1999   | 5/11/1999  |        55       |
|  9 | ghi  |  55  | 5/11/1999  | 5/11/1999  |        55       |
| 10 | ghi  |  83  | 3/28/1999  | 5/11/1999  |        55       |
+----+------+------+------------+------------+-----------------+
```

[(A shorter example is available as an image.)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvVQw.png)

Answer (score 0):

My reference is [here](https://exceljet.net/formula/index-and-match-with-multiple-criteria). TLDR : use the non-array version of the index-match formula.

In E2 put :

```
=INDEX(B:B,MATCH(1,INDEX((A2=A:A)*(D2=C:C),0,1),0))
```

Idea : the inside index() generate a 0 & 1 list that matched both name&date criteria. then the outside index() is used to 'load' the name from A:A .

Comment: This didn't work for me but I managed to get it to work by using:
=INDEX(B:B,MATCH(1,INDEX((A2=A:A)*(D2=C:C),0,1),0))

Comment: my bad... I load the name instead of ID. | updated answer. thanks for the head's up | Glad it works. ( : | If you don't mind.. you may accept the answer like [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). It'll remove this question from Superuser 'unanswered' list.

Comment: I have to test whether or not the non-uniqueness of the CreateDate will produce incorrect results - I suspect it might.

Comment: If the CreateDate is sequential (latest date = at the bottom), then check for NameMatch & MaxIDValue will do. Implementation : `=MAX(INDEX((A2=A:A)*(B:B),0,1))` | But if the CreateDate is not sequential, then I think we'll have a new case.

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses the offset match method. Using a match to find the date then offset based on the date to find the corresponding ID:

=OFFSET(C2,MATCH(D2,C2:C,0)-1,-1)

Drop this into the E2 cell then drag down throughout E

Answer (score 0):

For a given row (e.g., Row 2), you want to find the ID (Column `B`)
from a Row *n* (i.e., Cell `Bn`)
where the name (`An`)
equals the name from the current row (`A2`)
and the CreatedDate (`Cn`)
equals the LatestDate from the current row (`D2`). 
Row *n* is unique because the IDs are unique,
and so “***the***” row is the max row.
A logical answer would be a minor extension of your formula for Column `D`:

```
=MAX(IF(AND(A2=$A:$A,D2=$C:$C), $B:$B))
```

Unfortunately, `AND` doesn’t seem to work in array formulas. 
So we use a standard trick:
`TRUE` = 1 (or anything other than zero) and `FALSE` = 0,
so we can simulate `AND` with multiplication (`AND(TRUE,TRUE)` = `TRUE`
just as 1 × 1 = 1,
`AND(FALSE,anything)` = `FALSE`
just as 0 × *anything* = 0). 
So we change the above to

```
=MAX(IF((A2=$A:$A)*(D2=$C:$C), $B:$B))
```

(entered as an array formula,
with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, of course):

[image]

Note that this works with non-unique CreatedDates. 
It even works if the CreatedDates are not in the same order as the IDs,
as in the above example (where the data are sorted by Columns `A` and `B`).

Comment: I guess that this is functionally equivalent to [p._phidot_’s answer](https://superuser.com/q/1421093/150988#1421148) with a short array formula as opposed to a longer non-array formula.